# C# Font dialog disable style selection

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to disable only the "style" selection on the FontDialog window.
[font dialog without "style" list box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qbt1f.png)
It's possible?

For the moment when I applied the font, I overrride the style with the "regular" style. But I prefer to not enable the style selection.

User control Constructor

```
c#
public ProgramCtrl(){
    //...
    //other code
    //...
    fontDialog1.AllowScriptChange = false;
    fontDialog1.MaxSize = 10;
    fontDialog1.MinSize = 8;
    fontDialog1.AllowVerticalFonts = false;
    fontDialog1.ShowEffects = false;
    //...
    //other code
    //...
}
```

Event to set the Font

```
private void pbPrint1HeadFont_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fontDialog1.Font = tbPrint1Head.Font;
        if (fontDialog1.ShowDialog(this) != DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            editRecipe.RecPrms[183].Value = fontDialog1.Font.Size.ToString();
            editRecipe.RecPrms[179].Value = fontDialog1.Font.FontFamily.ToString();
            RefreshRecipeView();
        }
    }
```

Overrride of FontStyle

```
private RefreshRecipeView(){
    fontName = gSettings.GetFontFamily(editRecipe.RecPrms[179].Value);
    if (!float.TryParse(editRecipe.RecPrms[183].Value, out fontSize))
         fontSize = 8;
     tbPrint1Head.Font = new Font(fontName, fontSize, **FontStyle.Regular**);         
}
```

Comment: Which UI? WinForms, WPF, etc.? Please add a tag for it.

Comment: Some code example on how you open the FontDialog?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: So, if I prefer a heavier font for my usage, I can either ignore your program or have to design a font from scratch to have a heavier font weight by default because you don't want to respect a style option that is basically here for free, for some reason?

Comment: Yes, I need to filter the styles, because I have to use a specific printer cannot prints all style options